# XNA Game Studio extension not loading correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna

I just downloaded and installed `XNA Game Studio` extension for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and everything installed properly, but when I went to open a `.xnb` file using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 then I got an error message saying that `there is no editor available for 'C:/.../file.xnb'
Make sure the application for the file type (.xnb) is installed.`

What am I supposed to do to open a `.xnb` file?

Comment: is your XNA correct version? check here and reinstall if needed: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I just downloaded the latest version for Visual Studio 2013 (the version I have installed) last night